# NSDictionary length count is wrong

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

```
{
    Items = {
        Item = {
            text = "item 1";
        }
        Item = {
            text = "item 2";
        }
        Item = {
            text = "item 3";
        }
    }
}
```

Above is an example of my NSDictionary. Keep it in mind for this next snippet.

```
NSDictionary *dict = {the afore mentioned dictionary is here}
int count = [[[dict objectForKey:@"Items"] allKeys] count]; // Breakpoint here
NSLog(@"%i", count); // Breakpoint here
```

In my breakpoints, I get the following values for `count`

- On breakpoint 1: `count = (int) 128037184` (or some other random and big int)
- On breakpoint 2: `count = (int) 5`

I would have expected an int of 3 both times. What's going on?

Comment: Can you post the code where you build up the NSDictionary?

Comment: When you have a breakpoint in line 2, `count` might be sort of prepared but not exactly calculated. That might be a reason for being some random int, I guess?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the first case, you're breaking before the line is executed, so `count` will have whatever random data happens to be in that spot on the stack. If you step over that instruction in the debugger, you'll see `count` change to a more reasonable number.

In the second case, I'm not sure why you have more keys than you expect, but the simple thing to do would be to just log the entire dictionary and see what's there:

```
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

That'll show you all the keys and values in the dictionary, which may explain the number you're getting.

Comment: also note: when you stop at a line, it has not yet been executed

Comment: Thanks for the tips and I found that what I was looking for is `[[[dict objectForKey:@"Items"] objectForKey:@"Item"] count];` Also, this dict is built from an XML parser I found online. The extra items were two attributes (namespace and something else).

Answer (score 6):

I use [dict count] which gives you count of objects in NSDictionary.